# Column that increments based on foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Given a table of this format:

```
Primary | Foreign
1       | 1
2       | 1
3       | 1
4       | 2
5       | 2
6       | 3
7       | 4
```

Is it possible to describe a column that would act as an "order" or "sequence" column for each instance of the foreign key? Something that would behave like so:

```
Primary | Foreign | Seq
1       | 1         | 1
2       | 1         | 2
3       | 1         | 3
4       | 2         | 1
5       | 2         | 2
6       | 3         | 1
7       | 4         | 1
```

Specifically, I'm looking to define the the table to have discrete values in this column, but with the ability to change them. I can manage this behavior from the application, but was wondering if the default values could be managed on the db end. So, I would be looking for some magic that would make this work:

```
CREATE TABLE "MY_TABLE" 
        ( 
          "PRIMARY" NUMBER NOT NULL,
          "FOREIGN" NUMBER NOT NULL,
          "SEQUENCE" NUMBER DEFAULT SOME_MAGIC(SECONDARY, PRIMARY),
          CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY ("PRIMARY"),
          CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE_FK FOREIGN KEY ("FOREIGN")
          REFERENCES "SOME_OTHER_TABLE"  ("PRIMARY")
        )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, use `row_number`:

```
select primary, secondary,
       row_number() over (partition by secondary order by primary) seq
from yourtable
```

Comment: is it possible to to define a column in this manner though, with real discrete values, like perhaps using the default clause. Something like
`ALTER TABLE "MY_TABLE" 
        ADD ( SEQUENCE NUMBER DEFAULT SOME_FUNCTION(SECONDARY) )`

Comment: @MatthewGraves - [not really](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF54459); you could try to maintain it with a trigger but that's nasty. You can have a wrapper view that generates the value on the fly, or if you need to query based on it a materialised view doing the same thing might perform better.

Comment: @AlexPoole, yeah, I can maintain it in the application, I was just curious if there was a way to do it in the db.

Comment: @MatthewGraves -- I would highly advise against such an approach.  Maintaining it would be annoying at best... Not sure why a `view` wouldn't work, nothing to maintain at that point.

Comment: @sgeddes changing the order of the sequence wouldn't be possible in a view.

Comment: I didn't think this behavior was possible. Was just checking.

Comment: @MatthewGraves -- perhaps you could explain more, why would you want to change the order?  not completely understanding your concern.

Comment: @sgeddes Let's say that it represents the order of a list that can be rearranged.